# IIS Web Garden - File Access / Write from different processes

Tags: iis, logging, log4net, application-pool, web-garden

I host my web application on IIS.
The pool that application resides in has 4 worker processes. (Web Garden)

To make a test, for each requst to aspx page, I write the Process Id of Executing Process into log.net file log.

When I open the file log, I see **only the logs of first process**.

I am sure other processes are running beacuse I can see them in task manager.

May other processes have access problems to log file since first process is writing into it?
How can I write to same log file from different processes of same application pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to fix this is to let each worker process write to a different log file.

To do this you will need to use dynamic file names. See http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2009/03/03/dynamic-log-filenames-with-log4net.aspx
for an example.